# how to read a constant property in php extension?

Tags: php, php-extension, php-internals

I use `zend_declare_class_constant_stringl` macro to declare a constant property,but i don't konw how to read the constant?
the declare code :

```
zend_declare_class_constant_stringl(myclass_ce,ZEND_STRL("WEL"),ZEND_STRL("welcome\n") TSRMLS_CC);
```

I want use `zend_read_property` or `zend_read_static_property` to read the constant property but it doesn't work!

(1):
I use `zend_read_static_property`:

```
ZEND_METHOD(myclass,getName){
zval *name;
char *str;
zend_class_entry *ce;
ce=Z_OBJCE_P(getThis());
name=zend_read_static_property(ce,ZEND_STRL("name"),0 TSRMLS_CC);
str=Z_STRVAL_P(name);
RETURN_STRINGL(str,Z_STRLEN_P(name),1);
}
```

[root@localhost myext]# php -f /var/www/html/myclass.php

```
Notice: Undefined property: myclass::$WEL in /var/www/html/myclass.php on line 3
(null)PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: myclass::$name in      /var/www/html/myclass.php on line 5
```

(2) I use zend_read_property:

```
ZEND_METHOD(myclass,getName){
zval *name;
char *str;
zend_class_entry *ce;
ce=Z_OBJCE_P(getThis());
name=zend_read_property(ce,getThis(),ZEND_STRL("name"),0 TSRMLS_CC);
str=Z_STRVAL_P(name);
RETURN_STRINGL(str,Z_STRLEN_P(name),1);
}
```

[root@localhost myext]# php -f /var/www/html/myclass.php

```
Notice: Undefined property: myclass::$WEL in /var/www/html/myclass.php on line 3
(null)silenceperPHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: myclass::$BYE in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: A saying like *"it doesn't work!"* is a bit unspecific and it's not clear what you did expect actually and what happened instead. Care to share more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zend_get_constant_ex`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_constants.c#304):

```
zval c;

if (zend_get_constant_ex(ZEND_STRL("ClassName::CONSTANT_NAME"), &c, NULL, 0 TSRMLS_CC) == SUCCESS) {
    // ...
}
```

The `NULL` is the class scope to perform the fetch from (if you want to use something like `self`). The `0` are flags, e.g. `ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_SILENT`.

Comment: like this: `ZEND_METHOD(myclass,__construct){
    zval wel;
    zend_class_entry *ce; 
    ce=Z_OBJCE_P(getThis());
    zend_get_constant_ex(ZEND_STRL("self::WEL"),&wel,ce,0 TSRMLS_CC);
    php_printf("%s",Z_STRVAL(wel));

}
`    Total 1 memory leaks detected

Comment: @silenceper You have to `zval_dtor` the zval afterwards of course

Comment: It was the `ClassName::` that was missing, so useful this answer, though I'd like to ask, is there a good resource about PHP extensions with c?